Build a complex relation with query in Laravel with group by unique and having (or other suggestions)
I have 3 models:

Serie
Product
Property

A product can belong to a serie, so a serie can have multiple products.
A product can have multiple properties.
A property has a name/value and is filterable depending on the relation (pivot).
So I have the following database structure:
series



id
title
active




1
BMW i4 m50-serie
true



products



id
serie_id
sku
title




1
1
i4_m50_20_aut_bl
BMW i4 M50 2.0 automatic blue


2
1
i4_m50_20_aut_rd
BMW i4 M50 2.0 automatic red


3
1
i4_m50_20_aut_gr
BMW i4 M50 2.0 automatic green


4
1
i4_m50_20_man_bl
BMW i4 M50 2.0 manual blue


5
1
i4_m50_30_aut_bl
BMW i4 M50 3.0 automatic blue



properties



id
name
value




1
Transmission
Automatic


2
Transmission
Manual


3
Color
Blue


4
Color
Red


5
Color
Green


6
Engine
Electric



product_property



id
product_id
property_id
filterable




1
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_bl)
1 (automatic)
true


2
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_bl)
3 (blue)
true


3
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_bl)
6 (hybrid)
false


4
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_rd)
1 (automatic)
true


5
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_rd)
4 (red)
true


6
1 (i4_m50_20_aut_rd)
6 (hybrid)
false



Now I want to fetch in a single serie all the same properties of the serie.
All cars in de first serie are hybrid so i want to extract them from the product-properties to serie-properties.
So $serie->productProperties()->same()->get() would be nice so I can receive a collection of \App\Model\Property, but I don't know how.
With SQL it will be:
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `properties`.`id` ) AS `found_unique_count`,
`properties`.`id`,
`properties`.`name`,
`properties`.`value`    
FROM
`properties`
INNER JOIN `product_property` ON `product_property`.`property_id` = `properties`.`id`
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_property`.`product_id` 
WHERE `products`.`serie_id` = 1
GROUP BY `products`.`serie_id`, `properties`.`name`
HAVING `found_unique_count` = 1

Can you help me out?
I can provide an SQL-dump if required.
Thanks in advance!
